# Fulltext search multiple columns get which column matching

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

I use full-text search in SQL Server, I have a query like:

```
SELECT  [Column 12] AS Column_12 ,
        [Column 0] AS Column_0 ,
        [Column 13] AS Column_13 ,
        [Column 3] AS Column_3 ,
        [Column 4] AS Column_4 ,
        [Column 14] AS Column_14 ,
        [Column 5] AS Column_5 ,
        [Column 2] AS Column_2
FROM    dbo.allCountries
WHERE   CONTAINS (( [Column 12], [Column 0], [Column 13], [Column 3],
        [Column 4], [Column 14], [Column 5], [Column 2]), @Location )
```

What I need is to get which column matched the search value. If the search matched in more than one column, I need to get their names or indices.

Comment: Even without FullText, what you are asking is not possible in the structure you have....you will need to UnPivot the columns into a Multi-Join style table and get the information you need from that

Answer (score 0):

Based on your requirements:

```
select id, [column], value
from (
    SELECT [id]
        ,[column 0],[column 1]
        ,[column 2],[column 3]
        ,[column 4],[column 5]
    FROM [dbo].[allcountries]
    where contains (*, @location)
) tmp UNPIVOT (
    value for
    [column] in ([column 0],[column 1],[column 2],[column 3],[column 4],[column 5])
) up
where value like '%' + @location + '%'
```

This returns the `id` (identity, PK) field, `column` name ([column #]), and the searched for value (@location)